How to retain mathematical understanding and gain more
I am going through a stage where my mathematical intuition(Olympiad perspective)is taking a hit and the problems that I had solved seem unapproachable now.I had for 2 months quit a lot of proof based Olympiad maths to focus on computational form for contests, which may be the reason. Also, as I learn more it becomes difficult to retain it and gain more, for example I am developing some sort of fear and something like a paranoia that I am not able to understand stuff and I am not able to level up, the feeling I had before, I am following a book called Problems solving strategies by Arthur Engel for combinatorics as I am pretty weak at it. I had focused a lot on number theory and achieved a decent level before I stopped it to try geometry and combinatorics and now I feel under confident in number theory too.The joy I had is deteriorating where I would do maths problems late at night secretly. Now, I feel not to do them. How to get over this phase.
Any advice would be helpful.

A lot of people have been or are in your position, you will find more on this in the subreddit r/math.

Are you forced to do math? If not, just relax and do something else for a while. You will be back sooner than you think

@ClaudioMoneo No, at least for Olympiad math but for normal schools maths I have to. Yea I will try to follow this

@Krave37 off topic but were you an 2024 IMOTCer?
